# Why am I getting java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jnisgfplib in java.library.path even though IntelliJ shows no compilation errors, and how to fix?

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea, import, libraries

I set up a Java Application on Intellij to the point where the code compiles and runs. However when invoking one of the native libraries, I get `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jnisgfplib in java.library.path`, on the line:

```
    lib = new JSGFPLib();
```

where the import for `JSGFPLib()` looks like `import SecuGen.FDxSDKPro.jni.*;`

Here is what the project structure looks like, notice there are no compilation errors, and that the import I highlighted refers to the directory on the left containing `JSGFPLib`.

[image: Intellij]

Why am I receiving this error and how do I fix it? I am running this on a Mac, which should be able to run Linux Java Apps, since Java is JVM based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Java library has native dependencies which are OS specific.

You need these dependencies (native libraries) to be available in system `PATH` environment.

Another option is to specify `-Djava.library.path=<dir>` property in the **VM Options** field of the Run/Debug configuration where `dir` is the directory containing the native libraries for your OS.

IntelliJ IDEA can also recognize native dependencies automatically when they are added to the [module dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#working-with-module-dependencies) and will configure `-Djava.library.path` for you when running.